# CPF BRAZIL Jquery JS Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate cpf brazil, this code is in Jquery, and without using onclick or something similar in the input, I just need to get the input id in the form.

Follows the code:

```
jQuery(function(a) {
    var b = {
        init: function() {
            "0" === wcbcf_public_params.sort_state_country && a(document.body).on("country_to_state_changing", this.country_to_state_changing), "0" !== wcbcf_public_params.person_type && this.person_type_fields(), "yes" === wcbcf_public_params.maskedinput && (a(document.body).on("change", "#billing_country", function() {
                "BR" === a(this).val() ? b.maskBilling() : b.unmaskBilling()
            }), a(document.body).on("change", "#shipping_country", function() {
                "BR" === a(this).val() ? b.maskShipping() : b.unmaskShipping()
            }), this.maskGeneral()), "yes" === wcbcf_public_params.mailcheck && this.emailCheck(), a().select2 && a(".wc-ecfb-select").select2(), "BR" === a("#billing_country").val() && b.maskBilling()
        },
        country_to_state_changing: function() {
            a("#billing_state_field label").html(wcbcf_public_params.state + ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>'), a("#billing_postcode_field").insertAfter("#billing_country_field"), a("#shipping_state_field").length && (a("#shipping_state_field label").html(wcbcf_public_params.state + ' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>'), a("#shipping_postcode_field").insertAfter("#shipping_country_field"))
        },
        person_type_fields: function() {
            "no" === wcbcf_public_params.only_brazil ? (a(".person-type-field label .required").remove(), a(".person-type-field").addClass("validate-required"), a(".person-type-field label").append(' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>')) : a("#billing_country").on("change", function() {
                "BR" === a(this).val() ? (a(".person-type-field label .required").remove(), a(".person-type-field").addClass("validate-required"), a(".person-type-field label").append(' <abbr class="required" title="' + wcbcf_public_params.required + '">*</abbr>')) : (a(".person-type-field").removeClass("validate-required"), a(".person-type-field label .required").remove())
            }).change(), "1" === wcbcf_public_params.person_type && a("#billing_persontype").on("change", function() {
                var b = a(this).val();
                a("#billing_cpf_field").hide(), a("#billing_rg_field").hide(), a("#billing_company_field").hide(), a("#billing_cnpj_field").hide(), a("#billing_ie_field").hide(), "1" === b && (a("#billing_cpf_field").show(), a("#billing_rg_field").show()), "2" === b && (a("#billing_company_field").show(), a("#billing_cnpj_field").show(), a("#billing_ie_field").show())
            }).change()
        },
        maskBilling: function() {
            b.maskPhone("#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone"), a("#billing_birthdate").mask("00/00/0000"), a("#billing_postcode").mask("00000-000"), a("#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone, #billing_birthdate, #billing_postcode").attr("type", "tel")
        },
        unmaskBilling: function() {
            a("#billing_phone, #billing_cellphone, #billing_birthdate, #billing_postcode").unmask().attr("type", "text")
        },
        maskShipping: function() {
            a("#shipping_postcode").mask("00000-000").attr("type", "tel")
        },
        unmaskShipping: function() {
            a("#shipping_postcode").unmask().attr("type", "text")
        },
        maskGeneral: function() {
            a("#billing_cpf, #credit-card-cpf").mask("000.000.000-00"), a("#billing_cnpj").mask("00.000.000/0000-00"), b.maskPhone("#credit-card-phone")
        },
        maskPhone: function(b) {
            var c = a(b),
                d = function(a) {
                    return 11 === a.replace(/\D/g, "").length ? "(00) 00000-0000" : "(00) 0000-00009"
                },
                e = {
                    onKeyPress: function(a, b, c, e) {
                        c.mask(d.apply({}, arguments), e)
                    }
                };
            c.mask(d, e)
        },
        emailCheck: function() {
            a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").length < 1 && a("#billing_email").after('<div id="wcbcf-mailsuggest"></div>'), a("#billing_email").on("blur", function() {
                a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").html(""), a(this).mailcheck({
                    suggested: function(b, c) {
                        a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").html("Você quis dizer: " + c.full + "?")
                        alert("teste");
                    }
                })
            }), a("#wcbcf-mailsuggest").css({
                color: "#c00",
                fontSize: "small"
            })
        }
    };
    b.init()
});
```

The code above works perfectly, generates the masks and validates email addresses, in case I need to enter the CPF validation, so that it certifies that it is valid, the mask is 999.999.999-99, the input id is:

```
billing_cpf

<input type="tel" class="input-text " name="billing_cpf" id="billing_cpf" placeholder="" value="000.000.000-00" data-qa-id="CPF" required="required" maxlength="14">
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You already have the "maskGeneral" function that appears to apply to billing_cpf.  What exactly is the issue you're running into now?

Comment: Masks are being generated normally as you type in input

12345678911

11 CPF numbers

automatically gets the masks

123,456,789-11

What I really need to know is whether the number is valid or invalid.